# Pattern matching where failure case return type is Java void

Tags: scala, testng

In my tests I have code that looks like this:

```
val myVar = getVar() match {
  case Some(v) => v
  case None => fail() // TestNG
}
// more testing on myVar
...

// TestNG
public static void fail() { ... }
```

The problem is that `myVar` gets assigned the type of `Any`. What is the best way to deal with this situation?

Comment: Does `fail` throw an exception? If not what value should be assigned to  `myVar` after fail returned?

Comment: @bmaderbacher I was under the impression that `fail` throws an exception, but now I'm not sure. I'll check.

Comment: @bmaderbacher Yes, `fail` always throws an exception.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. JamesIry has beaten me with his answer :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First a bit of setup to match your environment(ish)

```
scala> def fail(): Unit = throw new RuntimeException("blah")
fail: ()Unit

scala> def getVar(): Option[String] = Some("hello")
getVar: ()Option[String]
```

Now write an adapter that returns Nothing instead of Unit

```
scala> def myFail(): Nothing = {fail(); ???}
myFail: Nothing
```

And the code works as expected when using the adapter

```
scala> val myVar = getVar() match {
 | case Some(v) => v
 | case None => myFail()
 | }
myVar: String = hello
```

Which, by the way, can be written more cleanly as

```
scala> val myVar = getVar() getOrElse myFail()
myVar: String = hello
```

More about the Unit type and its relationship to void http://james-iry.blogspot.com/2009/07/void-vs-unit.html
More about the Nothing type http://james-iry.blogspot.com/2009/08/getting-to-bottom-of-nothing-at-all.html

Comment: Does Scala treat the return value of a Java `void` method as `Unit` then?

Comment: If this is truly how it would work with a `void` Java method, then the problem in my code must be coming from somewhere else.

Comment: To you first question, yes, void and Unit are the same thing.

Comment: To your second comment, I don't understand. This is exactly where your problem is. The Java method "fail" has type Unit. The adapter method "myFail" has type Nothing.

Comment: @JamesIry Ah, I see. I misread the part of your answer explaining the adapter. You are correct.

Answer (score 1):

I'll just add one more possible answer. This uses the method @JamesIry described but with an inline partial function. It has the same effect, but is a bit shorter.

```
val myVar = getVar() match {
  case Some(v) => v
  case None => { fail(); ??? } : Nothing
}
```